# How to create a constructor of unknown number of variables and unknown type variables

Tags: c++, json, constructor

I have created a class named JSON that has three data types (`string`, `int`, `bool` ). I want to create a constructor that can get any of those types.
I dont want to create three separate constructors for the three data types, but one that can handle all of them.

The reason of me creating only one constructor is due to the fact that I want a constructor that can handle an unknown number of variables, and of unknown variable type.

The following constructor can get input of type: `JSON{1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 13, 3, ..., n}` with `n` of int type,
but not of type: `JSON{1, 2, 3, "hello", 2, 13, true, ..., n}`

```
JSON(initializer_list<int> init) : v(init) {}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `std::variant` could help

Comment: std ::variant is not working ...

Comment: `boost::variant` could help

Comment: U could use two iterators to start and end respectively. Then each iterator is some form of a json object. It is probably not very usefull to create a constructor for each possible way to initialize a json group eg.

Comment: neither does boost, I am running xcode it may be the problem ?

Comment: We can't do anything with the problem statement that `std::variant` and Boost "is not working".

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a limited number of types that is possible to send, I would create a struct that could be constructed with these values:

```
struct Value {
    Value(int i);
    Value(std::string s);
    Value(bool b);

private:
    // hold it using boost::variant, std::variant or an union.
};
```

The `Value` class is there to represent a value that can be constructed with either an `int`, a `std::string` or a `bool`.

Then, you can receive these instances in your initializer_list:

```
struct Json {
    Json(std::initializer_list<Value> values);
};
```

So there you're receiving a list of `Value` that each one can be constructed with an `int`, a `std::string` or a `bool`. Here's an example <kbd>[Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4063c8ba6b027c8)</kbd>

Comment: This is how JsonCpp does it.

Comment: what is the purpose of `Value(int i);` ?

Comment: @JohnTraveli It's a constructor that takes an `int` as parameter.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot that is what i thought but shouldnt there be something like: `Value(int i){int i_in = i;}`, and I assume I should initialize int i int private.

Comment: No. You should contain the `int` or `std::string` in a union like container.

Comment: I left the implementation of the constructors as an exercise to the reader. Use something like `boost:: variant` or a tagged union.

Comment: could you add some cout's to make it more understandable ? thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130806/discussion-between-john-traveli-and-guillaume-racicot).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom class with your data types as its members and pass this classes object to the constructor:

```
struct MyData {
    std::string strJsonVal;
    int intJsonVal;
    bool blnJsonVal;
};
```

Then, in your `Json` class, you can pass it to the constructor and get the value from the argument object:

```
Json(MyData strctMyData)
{
   strJsn = strctMyData.strJsonVal;
   intJsn = strctMyData.intJsonVal;
   blnJsn = strctMyData.blnJsonVal;
}
```

Comment: You should give an example in code of what you meant, and maybe more explanation.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot what part of this statement is not understandable that its needs a code to back it up

Comment: It is understandable, but not enough. Answers usually need examples, and this one is one of them.

Comment: stackoverflow is not about doing other peoples work and yes if the person asking the question puts a comment saying I am not following the suggestion in the answer then yes I am will to create a code for them. Supplying code is not an answer for every question by defacto standard

Comment: I did not mark your answer as not an answer. I only downvoted it because I don't think it's complete. If you are willing to improve it, I'll gladly upvote it.

Comment: It's a stretch to say that this is "not an answer", but it's equally a stretch to say that it's a useful one.